# update many in firebase real-time database React JS

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

is there any way to update many on firebase's real-time database? for example, in MongoDB, we can update many records like this [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/).
does firebase have this feature too?

I wanna update seen field to `true` for some records with specific `uid`

on MongoDB:

```
db.collection.updateMany({uid}, update)
```

[image]

Comment: please clear your question more so that I can help you with this

Comment: @SalmanShaikh I did